# R - How to expand each item in a list to include all days between the earliest date and today

Tags: r

I have a list of data frames. Each item contains the same columns. I want to add rows to each data frame so that it contains every day between the minimum date and today.  Here is my data:

```
lst <- list(c1 = structure(list(clientid = "c1", date = structure(17323, class = "Date"), 
                                type = "enquiry"), row.names = 1L, class = "data.frame"), 
            c100002 = structure(list(clientid = c("c100002", "c100002", 
                                                  "c100002", "c100002", "c100002", "c100002", "c100002", "c100002", 
                                                  "c100002", "c100002", "c100002", "c100002", "c100002", "c100002", 
                                                  "c100002", "c100002", "c100002", "c100002"), date = structure(c(13451, 
                                                                                                                  14571, 14824, 14862, 14869, 15159, 15201, 15435, 15589, 15834, 
                                                                                                                  15877, 16245, 16279, 16609, 17015, 17055, 17130, 17843), class = "Date"), 
                                     type = c("enquiry", "enquiry", "booking", "enquiry", 
                                              "enquiry", "enquiry", "enquiry", "booking", "enquiry", 
                                              "enquiry", "booking", "enquiry", "booking", "booking", 
                                              "enquiry", "enquiry", "booking", "booking")), row.names = 2:19, class = "data.frame"), 
            c100009 = structure(list(clientid = "c100009", date = structure(13734, class = "Date"), 
                                     type = "booking"), row.names = 20L, class = "data.frame"))
```

Which looks like...

```
> lst[1:3]
$`c1`
  clientid       date    type
1       c1 2017-06-06 enquiry

$c100002
   clientid       date    type
2   c100002 2006-10-30 enquiry
3   c100002 2009-11-23 enquiry
4   c100002 2010-08-03 booking
5   c100002 2010-09-10 enquiry
6   c100002 2010-09-17 enquiry
7   c100002 2011-07-04 enquiry
8   c100002 2011-08-15 enquiry
9   c100002 2012-04-05 booking
10  c100002 2012-09-06 enquiry
11  c100002 2013-05-09 enquiry
12  c100002 2013-06-21 booking
13  c100002 2014-06-24 enquiry
14  c100002 2014-07-28 booking
15  c100002 2015-06-23 booking
16  c100002 2016-08-02 enquiry
17  c100002 2016-09-11 enquiry
18  c100002 2016-11-25 booking
19  c100002 2018-11-08 booking

$c100009
   clientid       date    type
20  c100009 2007-08-09 booking
```

So, basically, I need to add rows for all days between each date up to today for each data frame in the list.

The 'clientid' column should be duplicated on each new row, however the 'type' column must show NA for any rows not in the original data.

I'd really appreciate any help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can loop through the `list` with `map` and use `complete`

```
library(tidyverse)
map(lst, ~ .x %>% 
             group_by(clientid, type) %>%
             complete(date = seq(min(date), Sys.Date(), by = '1 day')))
```